# Add GCP credentials to docker in .net core application

Tags: docker, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

Im new in docker.
I develop .Net Core Api which should use GCP Storage for file storage.
I used this tutorial to config https://medium.com/net-core/using-google-cloud-storage-in-asp-net-core-74f9c5ee55f5 but I have problem when I have to pass credential .json path.
How can I add credentials.json to docker container when docker-compose up ?
And what path would have this file on container

Comment: Can you add them to an environment variable as done https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Since you did not specify the Google Cloud service that you are using, this answer assumes Google Compute Engine combined with Docker.

If you are storing your service account in a JSON file on the container host, use the Docker `bind mount` feature. This example will map the host's `/secrets` directory to container's `/config` directory. Then you would access the service account using the full path starting with `/config/`

```
-v /secrets:/config
```

[Docker Bind Mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

However, the design of Google Cloud Compute services recommends assigning a service account to the VM instance and then accessing the credentials from the metadata. Google SDK Client use [ADC](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/) to locate credentials and will check the metadata for an OAuth Access Token if a service account is not specified. This includes the Google Client for .NET.

The Metadata endpoint to retrieve and OAuth Access Token:

http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1instance/service-accounts/default/token

Another option is to base64 encode the contents of the service account JSON file and pass to the container as an environment variable which you then save to a file inside the container (in your code, shell script, etc).

Comment: Note: never store your credential in your container! Use volume mount to load it as John described. You can also get inspiration from [there](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local)